# ggvis and data.table conflict?

Tags: r, data.table, ggvis

I am trying to run `ggvis` in combination with `data.table`, see code below.
I get the following error:

```
Error in `:=`(mpg2, mpg/2) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) 
  are defined for use     in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

If I run the line `mtcars[ , mpg2 := mpg / 2]` in the console there is no problem. So what is the problem? [I am still suspicious about the fact that both `data.table` and `ggvis` use `:=`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo = FALSE}
library(ggvis)
library(data.table)

mtcars %>%
  ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points()

mtcars = data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[, mpg2 := mpg / 2]  # gives error message

# code below does not work as the line above throws an error

mtcars %>%
  ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg2) %>%
  layer_points()
````

```

`data.table` version 1.9.2

`ggvis` from github 0.3.0.9001 as CRAN version complained about missing `knit_print`.

Comment: Do you get an error if you run the lines in an R session, instead of compiling the shiny document?

Comment: Its not a ggvis issue.  Comment out ggvis, and there is still an error.

Comment: Its not a ggvis issue.  Nor is it a markdown issue.  It has to do with shiny.  Delete `runtime: shiny`  and it works.

Comment: I think it's related to [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/187#issuecomment-52332667) and (if so) has been fixed in 1.9.3 by Matt today.

Comment: Yep. Or Henk can enter `assignInNamespace("cedta.override", c(data.table:::cedta.override,"rmarkdown"), "data.table")` if he'd prefer not to upgrade to v1.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated to data.table 1.9.3 and everything works like it should now. Thanks!